# Change-set SQL optimization

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to clean up a change-set query that returns rows from a table that have changed since a given time and also do not exist in a known list of already previously returned results.

```
select ID, Field1, Field2
from Table1
where Field = 'Foo'
and (
    ID not in ( %s )
    or (
       ID in ( %s ) and 
       GREATEST(created, COALESCE(modified, from_unixtime(0))) > from_unixtime(:stamp)
    )
)
```

Now using some basic 9th grade logic operators....

```
A or (B and C) = (A or B) and (A or C)
```

Except in my instance, A = "id not in (%s)" and B = !A. C = the date constraint. Which reduces to...

```
(A or !A) and (A or C) => A or C
```

So, following that logic, my where clause should now look like this, but it seems funky. Can anybody more experienced with SQL and/or logic tell me if I've missed something simple?

```
select ID, Field1, Field2
from Table1
where Field1 = 'Foo'
and (
    id not in ( %s )
    or GREATEST(created, coalesce(modified, from_unixtime(0))) > from_unixtime(:stamp)
)
```

Does that look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks all right. (but only looks so)

Beware! SQL logic is a 3-valued logic, **not** the same as the "usual" math logic. The three values are `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`.

In your case, if the `id` or the values in the `( %s )` list contain `NULL`, the two versions are not equivalent. Example: `5 NOT IN (6, 7, NULL)` and `5 IN (6, 7, NULL)` will both evaluate to `UNKNOWN` so no row will be returned by the 1st version. While the 2nd version will return the rows that satisfy the other condition `greatest() ...`.

If you have no Nulls, the two versions are equivalent.

---

You can find the truth tables in Wikipedia: [Three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)

Comment: Well I really appreciate you looking at it. I'll investigate whether or not nulls come into play. Thanks again!